# SimpleJdbcCall skipping first input parameter

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, java-stored-procedures, simplejdbccall

I am executing following code:

`simpleJdbcCall.withSchemaName("SCHEMA_NAME")
              .withProcedureName(storedProcdure)
              .addDeclaredParameter( new SqlParameter("INPUT_PARAMS",Types.LONGNVARCHAR));`

```
// Creating String of input numbers
if (!loanNumbers.isEmpty()) {
    for (String str : paramsList)
        finalInput = finalInput + str + ";";
    finalInput = finalInput + "'";
}
// Preparing map of input params for Stored Procedure
inputParams.put("INPUT_PARAMS", finalInput);
log.info("Input params for Stored Procedure :"+finalInput);

//Input Prepared and finally calling Stored Procedure
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource(inputParams);
Map<String, Object> resultSet= simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
```

If FinalInput have only one value ie. '123467', SimpleJdbcCall will omit this first parameters and I will not get any result. If I run the same SP in any IDE , for the same param , I will get the result.

If it have more than two parameters i.e '123467;98768', it will omit the first parameters(123467) and give result for 98768.

What is the reason for this kind of behavior and how can we fix this.

Comment: That might be something you need to lookup in the database it self.  Is there a reason to think JDBC is causing it?

Comment: If you have three or four parameters is it still skipping the first one, or is it that is only runs the last one?

Comment: Thanks @BrianC , Suppose I have 4 parameters for SP then SimpleJdbcCall is skipping result for the first parameter given as input and for other 3 input params I am getting results.

Comment: I observe that also. the problematic code is here: ```for (SqlParameter parameter : this.callParameters) {
   if (!parameter.isResultsParameter()) {
    if (parameterCount > 0) {
     callString.append(", ");
    }
    if (parameterCount >= 0) {
     callString.append(createParameterBinding(parameter));
    }
    parameterCount++;
   }
  }``` i do not know why in this code first parameter is just skip (parameterCount at the beginning is -1.